# How to compress N files to N .zip files respectively

Tags: file, zip, batch-processing

I am looking for an easy way to deal with the following case: compress ***N*** files and generate ***N*** separate .zip files.

<kbd>filename01.doc</kbd> will be compressed to <kbd>filename01.zip</kbd> which contains filename01.doc

<kbd>filename02.doc</kbd> will be compressed to <kbd>filename02.zip</kbd> which contains filename02.doc and so on...

Comment: What program are you using to create the ZIP files?  Is it one folder, or are they in subdirectories?

Comment: I am using 7zip, the files are all in the same folder.

Comment: Similar question: [Compress every file in a directory into its own compressed file](https://serverfault.com/questions/357066/compress-every-file-in-a-directory-into-its-own-compressed-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `path to 7zip` and remove the `/s` if you don't want to process subdirectories:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.doc /b /s /a-d ') do (  
   "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a "%%~dpna.zip" "%%a" 
)
```